# Making Java game, found easy way to cheat, don't know how to prevent it

Tags: java, timer

I'm making a game in Java, and I made it so that if you right click, the player teleports to the mouse to "escape". I want to make it so that you can only use it every 2 mins. and after trying and failing THAT, I found out that you can just hold down right mouse and the player will follow your mouse/clicker. I am using Processing 3.1.2 if that helps at all.

Comment: Please explain more and share some code so we can help.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you allow that player power to be used, note the current timestamp.

Next time the player attempts to activate that power, check the saved timestamp against the current time. If an insufficient number of seconds have passed, disallow the power.

If sufficient time has passed and you allow the power to activate, update the variable holding the time that the power was last used.

This is often called a "cool down" in games.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [javax.swing.timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). I have done this before, and within the mouseClicked event you set a boolean canTeleport = false. At the end of the javax.swing.timer, set canTeleport = true. The first thing that you can do when going inside mouseClicked,

```
if(canTeleport)
{
  //teleport
}
//start timer
```

Comment: Timer is overly complex. Just check time that the power was last successfully used.

Comment: It out any context, it's hard to be sure, but, starting another thread of any kind for this simple a task might not be the best idea, especially if all you need to do is compare the time between the last use and now :P